# Discord.js addRole alert to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so far `roles.add` works great

My code is

```
isMember.roles.add(myRole.id).catch(console.error);
```

However, I do not want to catch the error and display on console.

Instead I want an error message to be sent to the user.

I tried this but did not work.

```
 if(isMember.roles.add(myRole.id))
   msg.author.send("Success!");
 else
   msg.author.send("Error!")
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a role returns a promise. Promises can be handled by either using `then/catch` callbacks or `async/await + try/catch` blocks.

---

**Then/Catch**

The `.catch()` block will execute on an error - `.then()` on success - to send a message, simply do so in the function

```
isMember.roles.add(myRole.id)
   .catch(err => msg.channel.send("Error!"))
   .then(() => msg.channel.send("Success!");
```

**Async/Await + Try/Catch**

Make sure you're inside an `async` function

```
try {
   await isMember.roles.add(myRole.id);
} catch (err) {
   msg.channel.send("Error!");
}
```

Discord.JS' [Guide To Promises](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using functions in an `if` statement's condition is generally bad practice.  Instead, this seems like a good use for try/catch.  The `try` block attempts to execute the functions within it, and if an exception occurs, it'll move to the `catch` block instead.  For example:

```
try {
isMember.roles.add(myRole.id)
msg.author.send('Success!')
} catch {
msg.author.send('Error!')
}
```